# What is a "frozen ATPL"?

Tags: flight-training, easa-regulations

I've heard the term "frozen ATPL" and it seems to be some kind of limited EASA ATP certificate. What exactly is a frozen ATPL? What privileges does it give the holder? How is it unfrozen to become - presumably - a regular ATPL?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A frozen ATPL holder is somebody who has passed all the required (14) exams for the issue of an ATPL but does not have the required flying hours. Strictly speaking, there is no such thing as a 'frozen' ATPL, though a number of training schools [do use the term](http://www.askcaptainlim.com/becoming-a-pilot-pilot-68/1273-how-to-unfreeze-an-atpl.html):

> A Frozen ATPL holder refers to somebody who has passed all the required theoretical exams but does not qualify him to be issued with a full ATPL until he has logged a total of 1500 hours.
>
> A student from a flying school will normally graduate with a CPL (Commercial Pilot Licence) and IR (Instrumental Rating) (CPL+IR). This Licence is known as the Frozen ATPL.

In order to 'unfreeze' the ATPL, the candidate has to complete a flight time of 1500 hours [subject to certain conditions](http://digitalpilotschool.com/what-is-a-frozen-atpl/):

> ... ATPL will remain frozen until you have reached 1500 hours of flying time, which is made up of the following criteria:
>
> - 500 hrs multi-pilot in transport or commuter aircraft
> - 250 hrs PIC (or 100 Pilot in Command and 150 PIC under supervision)*
> - 200 hrs cross country flights (100 as Pilot in Command)
> - 75 hrs instrument time
> - 100 hrs night flight as PIC or co-pilot

Answer (score 5):

> A frozen ATPL is the name given to the qualification of a pilot who holds passes in all 14 ATPL theoretical exams. The ATPL becomes unfrozen when the flight experience requirements are met. This experience is normally achieved acting as first officer (flying right seat).

Basically this is the schooling portion of an ATPL, where the experience requirements are met on the job. Having a frozen ATPL is a requirement for employment as a first officer. The ATPL becomes unfrozen on the job when all the flight requirements are met.

Source: [aa-fta.com CPL With Frozen ATPL](https://web.archive.org/web/20161024161906/https://www.aaa-fta.com/courses/cplirmer-with-frozen-atpl/)

Comment: Since you've quoted a chunk of text from another site, it would be best to add the quoting markup to make clear what's your own commentary and what comes from the other site.

Comment: @Pondlife Added it, although it isn't exactly word-for-word.

Answer (score -1):

> A 'Frozen' Airline Transport Pilot Licence (ATPL) is the name given to the qualification of a pilot who holds passes in all 14 ATPL theoretical exams. The ATPL would become un-frozen when the flight experience requirements are met.

from: [Asian Academy of Aeronautics](https://web.archive.org/web/20161024161906/https://www.aaa-fta.com/courses/cplirmer-with-frozen-atpl/)

Comment: I'm not sure what this adds to the other answers, its almost directly the first two lines of my answer, and a direct copy/paste from the link I provided...

Comment: This appears to be copied and pasted [from another site](http://www.aaa-fta.com/courses/cplirmer-with-frozen-atpl/). Quoting from other sites is fine, but please add a link and use the quoting markup. Otherwise, it looks like you're trying to pass off someone else's content as your own (I'm not saying that was your intention here, only that it might look that way).