# How can I convert a frozen ATPL from South Africa to an Iranian one?

Tags: regulations, pilot-certification, icao-sarps

I have got a frozen ATPL license from South Africa and I'm from Iran. I came back home last year and I have converted my CPL/IR license to the Iranian piloting license by doing Air Law and Human Performance exams plus a skill test.

I'm willing to get the frozen ATPL license in Iran but I don't know what the rule is and if I can get it without doing the ATPL exams again.

I checked Annex 1 (Eleventh edition) but there wasn't anything about it. 
I assume both countries are following ICAO rules so I would appreciate it if someone helps me to know where or what the rule is.

Comment: This is a very specific question and I don't know if anyone here will be able to answer it. If not, I would simply ask the Iranian authorities about it. You said you've already converted your SA license to an Iranian one, so I guess you've had some contact with them already. And if you do find out the answer, please feel free to come back here and answer your own question!

Comment: And you might want to clarify what you mean by a "frozen ATPL".

Comment: @JuanJimenez I mean I have done all ATPL exams but I don't have 1500 hours so It's still frozen . So I would like to know If I have to do the exams in Iran again or not ?!

Comment: @JuanJimenez [You're not the only person](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/34100/62) who wondered about that :-)

Comment: I'm thinking you should talk to an aviation school that specializes in training for Iranian students, like http://www.paaviation.com or this one  www.apts.ir/en .